# Google+ API: Can I get friends' private information?

Tags: authorization, google-plus

I'm testing Google+ API v1.

I kepp fail to get my friends' personal information with the APIs with the authorization in the sandbox at the reference page.

I found the APIs in the documentation page, https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get, 
and I understood that I can get my friends' personal information if these are open to me.

Is it google's policy that I can only retrive public data regardless of the circular relation between me and my friend, or do I need any other authorization more than plus.login and plus.me.

Please help me, if you are familiar with Google+ APIs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current API only allows you to get public information about any user. Even if they have permitted the data to you, if it is not available to everyone, it won't be available in the API.